# Desigining a Form in j2me

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am trying to design a Form in J2ME without the use of **Canvas class** which has List like structure and an image as a Header.

I want to add  command button (OK) So by clicking on it ... i can choose a particular item in list and get navigated to next Screen.

Comment: so what is your question ?? have you got stuck anywhere ?

Comment: duplicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030146/desigining-a-form-in-j2me then by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031181/desigining-a-form-in-j2me

Comment: Yes the same duplicated... so the SOLUTION??

Comment: You say what you're trying to do, but not what you're tried nor where you're stuck.  It's very difficult to answer your "question" without either an actual question or even any details on where you're stuck.

Comment: http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/09/12/how-to-build-a-canvas-based-list-in-j2me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a ImageItem from that image. Take a form and add that image to the form. And to add list, if you are using netbeans ide, you can see various UI examples by doing this: File>New project>Category:Samples>UI Demo then click finish. And run the project. By observing the samples there you will have idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at [this](http://www.jappit.com/blog/2008/04/22/j2me-table-component-with-focus-and-scroll/) link. It tells how to create table(list) kind of layout using Canvas. It looks like Table with Row & Column. You can download example from [here](http://www.jappit.com/uploads/src/j2me_canvas_table_src.zip).

Comment: Thanks.. but i need to try it out first .. by the way where is the code for it

Comment: See, I have updated my answer. btw, you are "YC" from HNS ?

Comment: Thanks.. but i need an Implicit List and a Image header Without the use of Canvas Class ... The Link which you have posted has a Canvas Class Implemenentation

Comment: your name Yatin, I have friend of that name so I thought you might be him.

Comment: no..Sorry .. but do you have a solution

Comment: thats ok. I told you the solution I knew. I you want to do it in Form only ?

Comment: Yes ... an Implicit List like structure and an Image header in Form

Comment: NO...........................

Comment: The problem is in J2me i can't add an image and implicit looking list together together in form structure without the Canvas class.. 

So i tried by creating a Image and then a StringItem having 5 strings .Then i added an image as an header on Form , then the 5 strings to it . But now when i scroll through it and click on Ok Button ... how can i extract the StringText to the next Screen...

Comment: you need to add command to each StringItem, then you can do it.

Comment: Should i add ... like this StringItem str="Abc"

Comment: then str.setCommandListener()

Comment: str.addCommand(command_name);

Comment: OK .. now i added The str.addCommand(Command_name)

Comment: How can i come to know whether the particular StringItem is focused so when i click on corresponding command i can perform the action

Comment: while performing command action you need to check , which string has been clicked

Comment: i have accepted it as helpful .. now if i have two different StringItem and i have added the same Command Button as str1.addCommand(ok) and str2.addCommand(Ok) ... how come i could know which String item i have selected on clicking the Ok command

Comment: well when you have separate commands then in listener's click event method you can check which command has been press, based on that you can perform action.

Comment: public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(c==Ok)
  {
   
   String strText=stri[0].getText();Alert alert=new Alert(null, "Screen 1", null, AlertType.INFO);
   alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
   display.setCurrent(alert, form);
  
  }

Comment: Now how can i have alerts to which string i have selected if i got a Ok button to both the Strings str1 and str2